# norm1 reformulated linear programming

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

$\|x\|_1$ is a convex function as it's a norm, thus $-\|x\|_1$ is a concave function. The toy optimization problem as follows:

$$\min-\|x\|_1, \forall x \in R^n$$ is not a convex optimization problem as the objective function is concave. 
However if I try to reformulate it as a linear programming, I get: $$\min_{x,z \in R^n} \{-1^Tz \mid -z \le x \le z \}$$

It seems that I get somehow a linear programming which is a convex problem with an affine objective function. So this is contradictory to the previous statement. There must be something I forget or misunderstand. Could you point it out to me ?

Comment: What is the ordering considered here? As in, what does it mean for $x\leqslant z$ in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: the order here is element-wise, thus $x_i \le z_i \forall i \in [1,n] $

Comment: Your reformulated problem is unbounded. The optimizer will simply make $z$ go to infinity and all constraints are satisfied. The reformulation you used only makes sense for minimizing $|x|$ since then the optimizer has the incentive to push $z$ down and make it equal $|x|$ in the optimal point.

Comment: Thank you for point it out .